# Reference for a nice formula

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173887/distance-between-a-point-and-a-m-dimensional-space-in-n-dimensional-space-mn), $no identity$ gives a nice formula for the distance of a vector to a subspace:

$d^2(p,L)=\frac{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,p)}{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m)}\tag{1}$

Can anyone give me reference where I can find a proof of this formula.

Comment: you should answer your question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We show that the squared distance of a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to a subspace $L\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ spanned by the linearly independent vectors $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ is given by
$$d^2(v,L)=\frac{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,v)}{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m),}$$
where 
$$G(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle x_1,x_1 \rangle & \ldots & \langle x_1,x_k \rangle\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
\langle x_k,x_1 \rangle & \ldots & \langle x_k,x_k \rangle
\end{pmatrix}$$

is a Gram determinant.

Note that $(x_{1},...,x_{k})$ is a linear dependent family if and only if $G(x_{1},...,x_{k})=0$. Indeed, if $(x_{1},...,x_{k})$ is a linear dependent family, then there is $(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{k})\neq 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}x_{i}=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}L_{i}=0,$ where $L_{1},...,L_{k}$ are the lines of Gram matrix of $x_{1},...,x_{k}$. Conversely if $G(x_{1},...,x_{k})=0$, then there is $(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{k})\neq 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}L_{i}=0,$ where $L_{1},...,L_{k}$ are the lines of the Gram matrix of $x_{1},...,x_{k}$ as previously. Then we can see that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}x_{i}=0$ is orthogonal to all $x_{i}$, and is thus 0. Linear dependence follows. \

Now let $v=u+k$, where $u\in L$ and $k\in L^{\perp}$. By using the multi-linearity of the determinant, we find that

\begin{align*}
G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,v)&= G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,u)+G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,k)\\
                   &  =G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,u)+        \det \begin{pmatrix}
\langle v_1,v_1 \rangle  & \ldots & \langle v_1,v_k \rangle & 0\\
\ldots                   & \ldots & \ldots                  & \ldots\\
\langle v_k,v_1 \rangle  & \ldots & \langle v_k,v_k \rangle &0\\
*                        & *      & *                       & ||k||^{2} 
\end{pmatrix} \\
                  & =G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,u)+ G(v_1,\ldots,v_m)||k||^{2} 
\end{align*}
Now $G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,u)=0$, because $(v_1,\ldots,v_m,u)$ is a linear dependent family. So we get that 
$$||k||^{2}=d^2(v,L)=\frac{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m,v)}{G(v_1,\ldots,v_m)}.$$